# Node.js chat client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, chat, socket.io

This is a chat using Node.js, socket.io and MongoDB for storage.

I'd appreciate any feedback on what can be improved. I understand that this allows for non-unique usernames to be used, and it's currently a JavaScript prompt, however this is simply a demonstration for entering a username to test the functionality.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="chat">
            <div class="chat-messages"></div>
            <textarea placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <script src="node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

            (function() {
                var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080'),
                    name = prompt('Enter your name');

                // Listen for output from server
                socket.on('output', function(data) {
                    var messages = document.querySelector('.chat .chat-messages');

                    if(data.length) {

                        // Loop results
                        for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
                            var message = document.createElement('div');

                            message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                            message.innerText = data[x].name + ': ' + data[x].message;

                            // Prepend
                            messages.appendChild(message);
                            messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Listen for keydown
                document.querySelector('.chat textarea').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                    var self = this;

                    // Is enter down (without shift being held)?
                    if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) {

                        if(name) {
                            // Send message
                            socket.emit('input', {
                                name: name,
                                message: self.value
                            });

                            self.value = '';
                        }

                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            })();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;

client.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // Connect to MongoDB
    mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/chat', function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;

        var col = db.collection('messages');

        // Emit all messages
        col.find().limit(100).sort({_id: 1}).toArray(function(err, res) {
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit('output', res);
        });

        // Wait for input
        socket.on('input', function(data) {
            col.insert({name: data.name, message: data.message}, function(err, docs) {

                // Emit latest message to all clients
                client.emit('output', [data]);
            });
        });
    });

});
```

**main.css** (not as important here)

```
body,
textarea {
    font: 13px "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

.chat {
    max-width:300px;
}

.chat-messages,
.chat textarea {
    border:1px solid #bbb;
}

.chat-messages {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding:10px;
}

.chat-message {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.chat textarea {
    border-top:0;
    margin:0;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}

.chat textarea:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only open one connection to mongodb. Otherwise if you have 10 users connected on your chat, you'll have 10 opened connections to mongodb.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var sio = require('socket.io');

mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/chat', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

  var messages = db.collection('messages');

  client = sio.listen(8080).sockets;
  client.on('connection', function(socket) {
    messages.find().limit(100).sort({_id: 1}).toArray(function(err, res) {
      if(err) throw err;

      socket.emit('output', res);
    });

    socket.on('input', function(data) {
      messages.insert({name: data.name, message: data.message}, function(err, docs) {
        client.emit('output', [data]);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

From there, I would split the code into small functions. One could be call `onInputMessage` and looks something like.

```
var onInputMessage = function(data) {
  message.insert({name: data.name, message: data.message}, function(err, docs) {
    client.emit('output', [data]);
};
```

So that you can call it like this `socket.on('input', onInputMessage);`